# How to read snake case JSON request body in Go using Gin-Gonic

Tags: rest, go, go-gin

I am using [gin-gonic](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) to create my first [Go](https://golang.org/) rest API server.

My `User` struct is as follows

```
type User struct {
    FirstName string `json: "first_name"`
}
```

I have the following route defined in my code

```
route.POST("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {

        var user request_parameters.User
        c.BindJSON(&user)

        //some code here

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, token)
})
```

My `POST` request body is as follows

```
{
    "first_name" : "James Bond"
}
```

The value of `user.FirstName` is `""` in this case. But when I post my request body as

```
{
    "firstName" : "James Bond"
}
```

The value of `user.FirstName` is `"James Bond"`.

How do I map the snake case variable `"first_name"` from the JSON request body to the corresponding variable in the struct? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo (a space in `json: "first_name"`).

It should be:

```
type User struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
}
```